# Forwarding data to Oracle database

Tags: mysql, oracle, distributed

We have an application that collects the logs from various network devices and saves it in a MySQL database. This happens every 10 minutes.  The MySQL database keeps a week worth of logs.

Is it possible to make MySQL forward such logs to an Oracle database *if* any of the log messages match certain criteria? For example, MySQL should forward all logs if the line starts with "ABC".

Can this be done?

Comment: "Forward" how exactly? ... I'd say this calls for an application sitting in between the databases, and doing the data transfer

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it (I've mainly worked with Oracle, so the programming is on the Oracle side):

1. Create a DB link from Oracle to mySQL. Using the DB link Oracle
   can read tables in the mySQL database.  This requires [Heterogeneous Services](http://sysinfo.bascomp.org/oracle/setting-oracle-heterogenous-service-mysql-to-oracle/).
2. Set up an Oracle job that reads the MySQL table and inserts the records in an Oracle
   table. The job executes SQL that looks similar to this:

   `INSERT INTO oracle_log_table (field1, field2, field3)

       SELECT field1, field2, field3

       FROM mySQL_link.mysql_log_table

       WHERE mySQL_link.mysql_log_table.line LIKE "ABC%"

       AND _expression to check that the line is new_;`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL won't do it for you.  However you could use a script to automate this process.

You can use the `mysqldump` utility to get records matching your criteria for export to Oracle. Something like this (substitute your db user, db password, 'ABC' column name, database name and table name):

```
mysqldump --user=DBUSER --password=DBPASS --compatible=oracle 
    --no-create-db --no-create-info  
    --where="log_line LIKE 'ABC%'" 
    --result-file=sql_for_oracle.sql
    DATABASE_NAME TABLE_NANE
```

Then you can use `sqlplus` on Oracle to import `sql_for_oracle.sql` into Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [GoldenGate for MySQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18101_01/doc.1111/e17798.pdf) (see chapter 17 in [the Administrator's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E22355_01/doc.11111/e21513.pdf)).

Comment: Oracle GoldenGate is licensed separately from the database.